# Django: Invalid block tag: 'endif'

Tags: django

Here is the relevant template tag and html:

```
from django import template
from django.conf import settings

register = template.Library()


@register.inclusion_tag('auth_backend/templatetags/extends_layout.html')
def extends_layout():
    layout_template = getattr(settings, 'AUTHBACKEND_LAYOUT_TEMPLATE', '')
    return {'layout': layout_template}


{% if layout %}
  {% extends layout %} <<<<<<<<<<<<< Problem here
{% endif %}
```

When I use it in a view, I get the following error:

```
{# Sample view #}
{% load auth_backend_tags %}
{% load staticfiles %}

{% extends_layout %}
```

`Django: Invalid block tag: 'endif'`

If I delete `{% extends layout %}` then the error goes away, except my template tag is now blank.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible to put the [`extends`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#extends) tag in an if statement. From [the docs on template inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/language/#template-inheritance):

> If you use `{% extends %}` in a template, it must be the first template tag in that template. Template inheritance won’t work, otherwise.

You might be able to achieve what you want by using a variable with the extends tag, instead of an inclusion tag. You can set the variable in your view, or using a context processor.

```
def my_view(request):
    extends = getattr(settings, 'AUTHBACKEND_LAYOUT_TEMPLATE', 'default_base.html')
    return render(request, 'my_template.html', {'extends': extends })
```

Then in your `my_template.html`:

```
{% extends extends %}
```